# Give write-access to subfolder in read-only samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, read-only

I want to share one folder with specific access by users (one master with full and the others with read-only) and add subfolders in it which will be writeable by specific users.

Everyone is in the "users" group.
So I did this:

```
[Share]
path = /media/Share
comment = Doc, pictures, movies...
valid users = Master, User1, User2
force group = users
guest ok = no
browseable = yes
read only = yes
write list = Master
create mask = 0770
directory mask = 0770
force create mode = 0770
force directory mode = 0770

[User1's folder]
path = "/media/Share/Other folder/User1"
comment = User1's folder
valid users = User1
force group = users
guest ok = no
browseable = yes
writeable = yes
```

But Windows doesn't want to mount it as one drive, I have to mount the Share folder on one letter and the User1's folder on another, because as User1, the personal directory is read-only in the Share drive and writeable in the other drive... Could you help me please ?
I checked -stat folder and it's 777.

Comment: That is the nature of samba: 2 sections = 2 drive letters. You might get away with it by reversing the order: create sections for /media/Share/User1,  /media/Share/User2 where users can write and then symlink on linux to a /media/Share/readonly/ where the readonly stuff is (to prevent a loop I would put that on the same level).

Comment: So, I just have to put the [User1's folder] section in the smb.conf and "ln -s" the read-only folder (/media/Share/Content) in the User1's folder (/media/Share/User1/content) ?

Comment: yes and the same for User2 etc.

Comment: OK, because when I open the symlink with Windows, I have an "Access denied" error.

Comment: Guessing ;-)  but you need to tell samba to follow links `follow symlinks = yes` and `wide links = yes` from memory :)

Comment: Thank you ! That works. At first I had the same error, so I googled and it seems that new samba need [one more line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5120/how-do-you-make-samba-follow-symlink-outside-the-shared-path).
My problem now is that the symlink have the section's permissions, full access ^^' i'm working on it but if you know how to... :)